# UDP datagram Socket Programming with server in JAVA and Client in C++

Tags: java, c++, regex, sockets, udp

Below is the code for client server communication using UDP datagram protocol with server in JAVA and Client in cpp.

The task of the server is to read the data received from the client on its port and then unpack the string.
Now using String Builder we want to write that in the output file.

The problem which we are facing is that the output in the file is

javac UDPServer.java                         |  On terminal2 Running gcc -g client.cpp -o client

java UDPServer          | On terminal2 Running ./client

```
56,abcde^@,orange1
```

However the correct output should be

```
56,abcde,orange1
```

Also, pls check for closing of the file objects such as fo.close() and fw.close(), we have used finally block; Is that a good idea to close file descriptor objects?? Or shall we need to use some other techniques to close the file descriptor objects??

Below is the code for server:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.util.regex.*;


class UDPServer {
        public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception
        {
                FileOutputStream fo = new FileOutputStream("OUTFILE.txt",true);
                PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(fo);
                StringBuilder sb= new StringBuilder();

                DatagramSocket serverSocket = new DatagramSocket(11111);
                byte[] receiveData = new byte[1024];
                byte[] sendData = new byte[1024];
                try{

                        while(true)
                        {
                                DatagramPacket receivePacket = new DatagramPacket(receiveData, receiveData.length);
                                serverSocket.receive(receivePacket);
                                String sentence = new String(receivePacket.getData());
                                System.out.println("RECEIVED: " + sentence);
                                InetAddress IPAddress = receivePacket.getAddress();
                                int port = receivePacket.getPort();
                                System.out.println("Got packet form address:"  +IPAddress);
                                String capitalizedSentence = sentence.toUpperCase();

                                if (receivePacket != null && receivePacket.getLength() != 0) {
                                        String result = new String(receivePacket.getData());
                                        result = result.trim(); // remove leading and trailing whitespaces...
                                        String match_pattern="(\\d+)(a.*)(y.*)";

                                        //create a pattern object
                                        Pattern regexp_patternobject= Pattern.compile(match_pattern);

                                        //create a matcher object
                                        Matcher m_obj= regexp_patternobject.matcher(result);
                                        if (m_obj.find()){
                                                System.out.println("Found Value: " +m_obj.group(0) );
                                                System.out.println("Found Value: " +m_obj.group(1) );
                                                System.out.println("Found Value: " +m_obj.group(2) );
                                                System.out.println("Found Value: " +m_obj.group(3) );

                                                sb.append(m_obj.group(1));
                                                sb.append(',');
                                                sb.append(m_obj.group(2));
                                                sb.append(',');
                                                sb.append(m_obj.group(3));
                                                sb.append('\n');


                              System.out.println("StringBuilderValue: " +sb);

                                                 pw.write(sb.toString());

                                        }
                                        else
                                        {
                                                System.out.println("Matching Pattern Not Found");

                                        }



pw.write(sb.toString());

                                }
                        }
                }
                catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                }catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                }
                finally{
                        pw.close();
                        fo.close();
                }
        }
}
```

Comment: `^@` is the `null` escape, C strings are `\0` terminated, that could be why your output is `7,abcde^@,yellow1`. [C strings and C++ strings](https://www.prismnet.com/~mcmahon/Notes/strings.html)

Comment: how to avoid that??? in the output???

Comment: @Jim Garrison, pls guide what is going in printing output, how it can be overcome sir?? Also, sir pls check for the close of the file object descriptor in the finally block? is it a good approach? or something else better can be done for the same???

Comment: You don't actually implement any protocol, you just send some raw binary data as if it was assembled correctly to comply with the requirements of your protocol. Point to the part of your code that arranges the bytes you send as required by the protocol, you cannot do it.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz, in the application it is using protocol sir, what ever i presented above is the pseudo code to the actual application.

Comment: If the provided code is not accurate, how can you trust the answers?

Answer (score 2):

Your C program is sending a stream of bytes representing the contents of a `struct ssi_dump_nmsdata_type` instance.

```
typedef struct {
     char rssi;
     unsigned char bssid[6];
     char ssid[16];
} ssi_dump_nmsdata_type;
```

The `bssid` field is a 6-byte array of `unsigned char`, and in the instance you show the value is `abcde` in the first 5 bytes with the last byte being 0x00.  In C that would be taken as the end-of-string character and not printed.  Strings in Java are not null-terminated so that character is being printed.

You need to change the code in Java that unpacks the struct to better cope with the possibility of one or more trailing null bytes (`0x00`) in the `bssid` and `ssid` fields.  Regular expressions are a bad idea here, and what you've got so far will fail as soon as you receive a BSSID that doesn't start with `a` or an SSID that doesn't start with `y`.

You should first split up the buffer based on character count (1, 6 and 16 bytes) and then remove any trailing null bytes from BSSID and SSID.

However you should be aware that what you are doing glosses over some important and subtle details. When you do (in Java)

```
String result = new String(receivePacket.getData());
```

The received data is being *decoded* from a byte stream to a Java Unicode character string *using the default encoding*. If the stream contains non-ASCII byte values (outside the range 0x00-0x7f) you may get unexpected results.  Explaining all the ramifications in detail is beyond the scope of what SO is intended for.

You should investigate and learn about the difference between a byte stream (what you C program is sending) and a Java String.  You should be splitting up the fields of the struct from the byte stream first, as bytes, before converting them to Java String instances.   The buffer classes in `java.nio` are intended for just this purpose, so I recommend you follow some tutorials on "Java NIO Buffers".

Comment: sir it will be greatful if u can guide us with some reference on this topic or provide us some similar link to avoid regex and use something different?

Comment: sir hw about splitting the string which we have made in java code as String result = new String(receivePacket.getData()), by using substring method and providing the value of the position which we know are 1,6,16.

Comment: You can do that but as I said, if the buffer contains non-ASCII data you may get very unexpected results.

Comment: sure, will go with "Java NIO Buffers"

Answer (score -1):

UDPServer.java has no problem .
 the problem comes from cpp client.
 I recommend you to fix like this:

bssid length: from 6 to 5.

Comment: sir thnx for sharing ur views, we request you to also check for the closure of the file object descriptor in the finally block? is it a good approach? or something else better can be done for the same???

Comment: I think we don't need 2 close. just one close (pw or fo ).close will be enough. thank you

Comment: I don't quite understand your question.. I think the best choice is openning fo in try phrase. and no close.. like this.  
try ( FileOutputStream fo = new FileOutputStream("OUTFILE.txt",true) ){
   //it will close automatically
}catch (Exception e){}  //JDK must be above 1.7

Comment: Thnx Gary, Also pls suggest me some good idea how should we first split up the buffer based on character count (1, 6 and 16 bytes) and then remove any trailing null bytes from BSSID and SSID.

Comment: I think you are making this for specific purpose like nms.. so it is difficult for me to recommend.  But if I make this as general purpose, I would use comma as a separater. And then variable length data can be sent. And there will be no size problem. ( this is Just my thought not recommend.) Thanks.